# How to open all the Bootstrap 5 accordions simultaneously without closing the ones that were already open

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have an accordion

How can I open all the accordion items at the same time when clicking on a single Accordion Item?

Let's say we have this scenario:

Accordion Item #1 open

Accordion Item #2 closed

Accordion Item #2 closed

If we click on item #2 or #3, the three accordions will be opened (the Accordion #1 will remain opened) and then if we click again on some Accordion Item, the 3 accordions will close simultaneously.

```html
<body>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

@nontechguy Answer edited:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
               <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".panelsStayOpen">
               Accordion Item #1
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="" class="panelsStayOpen accordion-collapse collapse show">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
               <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".panelsStayOpen">
               Accordion Item #2
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="" class="panelsStayOpen accordion-collapse collapse">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
               <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".panelsStayOpen">
               Accordion Item #3
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="" class="panelsStayOpen accordion-collapse collapse">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/#always-open

Comment: @nontechguy Thanks for the answer, no, basically that's what I did with the first Accordion Item (`class="accordion-collapse collapse show"`), what I want is what I described in the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, starting to solve part of your request?
All the accordian-items will open and close simultaneously when clicking any accordian-item.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
               <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".panelsStayOpen">
               Accordion Item #1
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="" class="panelsStayOpen accordion-collapse collapse">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
               <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".panelsStayOpen">
               Accordion Item #2
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="" class="panelsStayOpen accordion-collapse collapse">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
               <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".panelsStayOpen">
               Accordion Item #3
               </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="" class="panelsStayOpen accordion-collapse collapse">
               <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, now all the items open simultaneously but here comes the tricky part: how to keep all the items open if there was a previously opened Accordion Item?

Comment: I edited your code and updated my question. As you can see, if Accordion Item #1 is open by default (with the always option that you mentioned earlier) and we click on some Accordion Item, the Item #1 will be closed and items #2 & #3 will be opened simultaneously. How can I keep all of them opened simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Bootstrap has anything by default for your test case. What you want is to detect the `show` or `hide` events on the collapse, and then manually control every accordion. I took the basic example from their documentation, and modified it. Do you want something like this?

```js
const accordion = document.getElementById('accordionExample'),
        accordionCollapses = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-collapse'));

accordionCollapses.forEach((accordionCollapse) => {
  accordionCollapse.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', (event) => {
    accordionCollapses.forEach((accordionCollapse) => {
      accordionCollapse.className = 'accordion-collapse collapsing';            
      accordionCollapse.style.height = '100%';
      setTimeout(() => accordionCollapse.className = 'accordion-collapse collapse show', 350);
      accordionCollapse.parentElement.querySelector('.accordion-button').className = 'accordion-button';
    });
  });

  accordionCollapse.addEventListener('hide.bs.collapse', (event) => {
    accordionCollapses.forEach((accordionCollapse) => {
      accordionCollapse.className = 'accordion-collapse collapsing';
      accordionCollapse.className = 'accordion-collapse collapse';
      accordionCollapse.parentElement.querySelector('.accordion-button').className = 'accordion-button collapsed';
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
          <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Accordion Item #1
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            Less content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Accordion Item #2
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow. <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow. <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
          <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Accordion Item #3
          </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle, if you need.](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/cbzLafos/33/)

Comment: Thank you, excellent, that's basically what I need but do we need the timeout? Is not possible to show/collapse all the items simultaneously without setting a timer? The transition does not look good tbh

Comment: The timeout is so all the items open and close completely at exactly the same time. The transition however, yeah I see it looks bad. I'll try and fix it, will update if I am able to!

Comment: Okay yeah, just needed to add a height (like bootstrap does), and the transition is already defined in their CSS. Made the changes to the JS!

Comment: Sorry but I've been testing your code and I found another problem, your solution is setting a `height = '104px'`, which is great when the content of the accordions is small but if we have large contents then it's messed. Could you check it?

Comment: I made some changes, however it doesn't transition anymore when closing. This is the best I can do, I guess.